# Response for CORS preflight is 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Tags: angular, cors, foursquare, angular-http, http-status-code-405

I am trying to upload foursquare user's profile photo from my angular web application. I am using "users/update" end point -
 https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/update

Here is my template,

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
```

Here is my component code,

```
fileChange(event) {

    let fd:FormData=new FormData();
    fd.append("photo",event.target.files[0]);

    let headers=new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
    headers.append("Accept","application/json");
    headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","true");


    let options=new RequestOptions({headers:headers});


    this.http.post("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/update?oauth_token=myauthtoken&v=20160108",fd,options)
    .map(response=>response.json())
    .subscribe(                                      
             data=>console.log(data),
             error=>console.log(error)                                     
    );
}
```

I am getting **405 (Method Not Allowed)** and **Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405** errors in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to start by removing the following from your frontend JavaScript code:

```
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","true")
```

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header for servers to send; the only effect adding it as a request header will ever have is to trigger a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) that’ll fail.

What you see happening now is that because your code adds `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header, your browser is sending a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests); and for the browser to consider that preflight successful, the `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/update` endpoint must respond to the `OPTIONS` request with a 200 OK or 204 status code.

But that 405 “(Method Not Allowed)” response you’re getting instead indicates that Foursquare API endpoint isn’t configured to handle `OPTIONS` requests. So the preflight fails and your browser never moves on to doing the `POST` request your code it trying to send.

However, responses to non-`OPTIONS` requests from that Foursquare API endpoint do include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. So the code in the question should work as expected as long as you’re not adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the client side, and as long as there’s no other characteristic of the request that will trigger browsers to do a preflight.

Answer (score 0):

If this issues occurs on IIS after deployment, i will suggest you add this on your Web.config inside  tag:

```
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```